# How to move header and footer on left or right?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have a really nasty problem. I have to move page body OR header and footer on left or right on few pages in mid document, but I cant use a lot of useful stuff:

- `geometry` package
- `\textwidth` options
- cant change margins - this makes footer and header move to the left border
  becouse it makes issues to the rest of figures in document.

The solution is quite obvious:

1. move header, footer in left/right
2. move only page body.

Comment: This is not clear. And it will be better if you post example of your document

Comment: How can you move the body if you can't change the margins?  By definition, the margins are the space between the text area and the sides of the paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. What we need is
edit:

```
\fancyheadoffset[LO,RE]{<dim>}
\fancyheadoffset[RO,LE]{-<dim>}
```

Here the complete example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}



\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{page \thepage}} 
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{machin}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{page \thepage}} 
\fancyfoot[L]{truc}
\fancyfoot[R]{\leftmark}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\section{Test}
\lipsum[1-15]

\fancyheadoffset[LO,RE]{2cm}
\fancyheadoffset[RO,LE]{-2cm}

\section{and test}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\fancyheadoffset[LO,RE]{<dim>}
\fancyheadoffset[RO,LE]{-<dim>}` and `\fancyfootoffset[place]{length}` do what I wanted. Thank you. I was looking into fancyhdr documentation but I didnt find this. Meh..

Comment: \fancyfootoffset[place]{length} add <length> to header in <place> so \fancyheadoffset[LO,RE]{<dim>} add <dim> to left part of oddpage and right par of evenpages

Comment: Yes. I did it already. Thank you once again :)